# How to learn c++ generic programming and template?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

How to learn c++ generic programming and template? Recommend some good books about this topic.

Comment: Shouldn't this be community wiki?

Answer (score 6):

- [C++ Templates: The Complete
  Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) - D.Vandevoorde and
  N.Josuttis
- [C++ Template
  Metaprogramming: Concepts, Tools, and
  Techniques from Boost and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321227255) - D.Abrahams and A.Gurtovoy
- [Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming and
  Design Patterns Applied](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315) -
  A.Alexandrescu

Answer (score 4):

[C++ Templates: The Complete Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201734842) by *Nicolai M. Josuttis* is a good book for templates.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Standard Library by Josuttis.

Answer (score 0):

[Modern C++ Design: Generic Programming And Design Patterns Applied](http://www.flipkart.com/modern-design-andrei-alexander-generic/0201704315-jqw3f8btab)
[shameless promotion]Also check the [loki-lib](http://loki-lib.sourceforge.net/) that was written for the book. I am a developer. :)[/shameless promotion]
EDIT: Also take a good look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/622659/what-are-the-good-and-bad-points-of-c-templates)